# find the nth occurence of a substring in a string in java?

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a string that is the complete content of an html page and I am trying to find the index of 2nd occurence of `</table>`. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: @Jon: How do you know this is homework? @Tijo: Is it? Or are you trying to do this in a real program you're writing. Homework is fine as long as you say.

Comment: I imagines its similar to these ;) http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=find+the+nth+occurence+of+a+substring+in+a+string+in+java

Comment: is there any problem in my question..? i have a string that is the complete content of an hhtml page..and i want to know the index of 2nd occurence of "</table>" i that ...

Comment: @T.J. I think that most people writing real program are able to look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html and search for word *occurrence* on this page. And find out which occurrence of word *occurrence* marks the most suitable function.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder :homework..?????what you mean..?yes am trying to implement this in a real project am working,..

Comment: @Tijo: What I meant as that @Jon tagged your question "homework" (school work). I thought it was a bit of a rash assumption, so I asked you if he was correct. I've removed the tag for you (well, @Mike did, I just approved the edit).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: sorry..i dnt understand what you mean..@Jon Bright:

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: sorry..i dnt understand what you mean..              @Jon Bright:its not a homework..when am trying to do this i have confused..thats why am post this question..@Peter Lawrey: first i searched for this answer in google..i can't get an apt solution to this..@all: sorry again if i had done something wrong with this question

Comment: @Tijo K Varghese There is nothing wrong with it now, but in the future try to be more specific with the actual problem you are having. You started by asking how to find the second occurrence of any substring, but in your comments you were able to describe the exact situation where you needed it. Try to be more specific next time with what the problem is and what you have tried or searched already. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a shot for fun ;)

```
public static int findNthIndexOf (String str, String needle, int occurence)
            throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    int index = -1;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(needle, Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while(m.find()) {
        if (--occurence == 0) {
            index = m.start();
            break;
        }
    }
    if (index < 0) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    return index;
}
```

Comment: isn't a < a special character in regex that you should escape? http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Regular_expressions_3__Anchors.html

Comment: @Bas - no, it is not a special character in Java's regex: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

Answer (score 6):

A generalization of [@BasVanDenBroek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5678546/829571), using indexOf:

```
public static int nthIndexOf(String source, String sought, int n) {
    int index = source.indexOf(sought);
    if (index == -1) return -1;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        index = source.indexOf(sought, index + 1);
        if (index == -1) return -1;
    }
    return index;
}
```

Quick and dirty test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println(nthIndexOf("abc abc abc", "abc", 1));
    System.out.println(nthIndexOf("abc abc abc", "abc", 2));
    System.out.println(nthIndexOf("abcabcabc", "abc", 2));
    System.out.println(nthIndexOf("abcabcabc", "abc", 3));
    System.out.println(nthIndexOf("abc abc abc", "abc", 3));
    System.out.println(nthIndexOf("abc abc defasabc", "abc", 3));
    System.out.println(nthIndexOf("abc abc defasabc", "abc", 4));
}
```

Comment: This one is better than accepted solution because that other one uses pattern matching and thus slow. This one is two orders magnitude faster

Answer (score 5):

Another good option for finding the Nth occurrence of a String is to use [StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#ordinalIndexOf%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int%29) from Apache Commons:

```
StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf("aabaabaa", "b", 2)  == 5
```

Comment: +1 as it's always better not to reinvent the wheels.

Comment: Not 'another good option', simply the best/safest/quickest option. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

First find the first index, then look for the second index starting your search from the first index +1

```
String string = "first</table>second</table>";
int firstIndex = string.indexOf("</table>");
int secondIndex = string.indexOf("</table>", firstIndex+1);
System.out.println("second index: " + secondIndex);
```

This is some pretty basic code btw, you will want to build some additional checks (index != -1 and the like)
Also in your post title it said nth occurence but in your post you mention the second occurence specifically. I'm sure you'll be able to figure it out from here if you actually need the nth occurence though.

Answer (score 0):

Working further on https://stackoverflow.com/a/5678546/15789 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/14356988/15789 (Thanks to original posters @sebastiaan-van-den-broek and @assylias).

Get all the indices in an array. Then you can get any nth index. In many cases, it may be required to get the nth index of a substring within a string multiple number of times. Getting an array once and accessing it multiple times may be easier.

```
public static int[] getIndices(String source, String substr) {
    List<Integer> indicesList = null;
    int index = source.indexOf(substr);
    if (index == -1) {
        return new int[0];
    } else {
        indicesList = new ArrayList<>();
        indicesList.add(index);
    }

    while (index != -1) {
        index = source.indexOf(substr, index + 1);
        if (index != -1) {
            indicesList.add(index);
        }
    }

    // Integer[] iarr = new int[1]; 
    //Autoboxing does not work with arrays. Run loop to convert. 
    //toArray does not convert Integer[] to int[]
    int[] indices = new int[indicesList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < indicesList.size(); i++) {
        indices[i] = indicesList.get(i);
    }
    return indices;
}
```