# Match Specific Index

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching, match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [find the nth occurence of a substring in a string in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678152/find-the-nth-occurence-of-a-substring-in-a-string-in-java)

Is there any way to get a specific match in a string?

If we have `String test = "this is a long test which is a test of a test";` then can we use `Matcher` to get the **second** (or any specific) instance of `test`?

I thought I could use `Matcher.find(x)` but that doesn't seem to work too well...

Comment: @Threat do want to find contain word?

Comment: If what you want to find is literal string, then just use indexOf. If you want to find the 2nd occurrence that matches a regex, then you can also use the Matcher loop with counter. It is also possible to do so on first find with Pattern/Matcher.

Comment: @nhahtdh You can also use `indexOf(char, int)` in a loop.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: There is no method with that signature in String class.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
int firstIndex = string.indexOf("test");
if (firstIndex >= 0) {
    int secondIndex = string.indexOf("test", firstIndex+1);
}
```

Also, you can make a loop of that if you want the n-th occurrence:

```
int nthIndex = -1;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
    nthIndex = string.indexOf("test", nthIndex +1);
    if (nthIndex < 0) {
        break;
    }
}
```

This will give you the nthIndex, or -1 if not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf` method to do this.

```
    String string;
    int one = string.indexOf(strToBeSearched);     
    int two = string.indexOf(strToBeSearched, one+1);
```

Additionally, you should check if `one` is >= 0 (if `strToBeSearched` doesn't exist inside string, `indexOf` will return -1)

Answer (score 0):

I think this func could do the job

```
int find(String s, String pattern, int occurence) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(s);
    for (int i = 1; m.find(); i++) {
        if (i == occurence) {
            return m.start();
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```